# Why do two tables with valid geometry return self-intersection errors when intersected?

Tags: postgis, sql, geometry, st-intersects

I have two tables A and B, both have valid geometries when I check with `ST_IsValid`. In my query, I intersect the two and the query stops in the middle because of this error:
`ERROR:  lwgeom_intersection: GEOS Error: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point`

I read [ST_Union fails with TopologyException despite valid polygons and using ST_SnapToGrid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229367) which seems very similar, and tried the `ST_CollectionExtract` as mentioned in the accepted answer, but I still the same error.

When I run the query on a subset of the data I notice some records are ST_MultiPolygon while others are ST_Polygon, is this causing the issue and, if so, how can I fix it?

The original query has other fields which I've left out here but it generally looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(r.geom, 5070), 
                                        ST_Transform(c.geom, 5070)),3) as geom,
   a.place,
   b.name

FROM table1 as a 
JOIN table2 as b
WHERE a.geom && b.geom
AND ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(r.geom, 5070), ST_Transform(c.geom, 5070))
```

I am projecting it because I also calculate areas in the full query.

Comment: Reprojecting geometries can harm self-integrity, even without intersection.

Comment: @Vince Data was originally in 4326 but since I need to calculate area coverage and density I need to be able to go to meters and then feet. How can I go about this if it's best to avoid reprojecting the data?

Comment: I'm not saying to avoid projecting the data, just that some projections corrupt some geometries.  I am also suggesting that focusing the question on the place where the error occurs will make it easier to solve. BTW: You can compute a geodesic area by casting to `geography` (if not using a buggy PostGIS) -- the units will be meters.

Comment: just because the two input geometries are valid doesn't imply that the intersection is a valid geometry.

Comment: note that you wouldn't need to transform the filter geometries (`ST_Intersects`). you can also create the `ST_Intersection` without projection, and, as @Vince pointed at, cast (`::`) the input to `ST_Area` to `GEOGRAPHY` to receive precise measurements with meter as unit. both would increase performance significantly, as PostgreSQL can lookup the spatial index on the initial tables (transformed geometries are not covered by those indexes, so lookup will be sequential and slow). note that, technically, this still doesn't guarantee a valid intersection geometry, but reduces the chance for them.

Comment: @IanTurton actually in PostGIS the intersection of two valid geometries should always be valid (or in rare cases will cause an error, due to robustness problems)

Comment: As noted above reprojection can cause a valid polygonal geometry to become invalid.  In this case `ST_MakeValid` could be used to ensure the transformed polygons are valid.

Answer (score 2):

To resume:

The reprojection seems to be the problem here. If your need is to have an area in meters, the simplest way, as you have 4326 geom, would be to use the geography type:

Add an indexes on your geoms casted as a geography (to speed up the intersection search):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table_1_geog ON table_1 USING gist (CAST(geom AS geography));
CREATE INDEX idx_table_2_geog ON table_2 USING gist (CAST(geom AS geography));
ANALYZE table_1; ANALYZE table_2;
```

Change your request to use geography (also you don't need bounding box comparison, ST_Intersects automatically use it):

```
SELECT 
        ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(a.geom::geography, b.geom::geography),3) as geom,
        a.place,
        b.name
    FROM table1 as a, table2 as b
    WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom::geography, b.geom::geography);
```

Comment: Jut be cautious that an st_intersection on geographies involves reprojecting to the "best" local projection first (like UTM), which can throw the same error. Using ST_MakeValid on the manually reprojected geometries might be safer.